# Get function pointer's function name using macro # not working

Tags: c++, templates, macros, function-pointers

I have a helper class defined like this:

DataGuard.h

```
template<typename T, typename D>
class DataGuard {
public:
  typedef MY_STATUS( *FunctionType )( const T*, D* );

private:
  bool               _isSuccess;
  D&                 _data;
  const FunctionType _function;

public:
  explicit DataGuard( D& data, FunctionType& function, const T* ptr );
  ~DataGuard();
  bool isSuccess() const;
};
#define DATAGUARD( Type ) const DataGuard<Type, Type##Data>

#include "DataGuard.inl"
```

DataGuard.inl

```
#define GET_FUNCTION_NAME( functionName ) #functionName

template<typename T, typename D>
DataGuard<T,D>::DataGuard( D& data, FunctionType& function, const T* ptr ) :
  _data( data ),
  _function( function )
{
  auto iReturn = function( ptr, &data );
  _isSuccess = iReturn == MY_SUCCESS;
  if( !_isSuccess ) {
    Utility::logErrorMessage( GET_FUNCTION_NAME( _function ), iReturn );  
  }
}

template<typename T, typename D>
DataGuard<T,D>::~DataGuard() {
  if( _isSuccess ) {
    _function( NULL, &_data );
  }
}

template<typename T, typename D>
bool DataGuard<T,D>::isSuccess() const {
  return _isSuccess;
}
```

This helper class is being called like this:

```
DATAGUARD( MyObject ) guard( data, MyObjectGet, ptr );
```

The problem is that if there is an error in the DataGuard constructor, the error message that I print is showing **_function** rather than the desired **MyObjectGet** function name.

Any ideas why the GET_FUNCTION_NAME macro is failing me?

Comment: You might want to read up on what preprocessors actually do. `GET_FUNCTION_NAME(_function)` will result in `#_function`, which will result in `"_function"` after string-izing. You need a macro that constructs a data-guard object that takes an additional argument (the string-ized function name), and drive this from the caller site, not the callee site.

Comment: There are some compiler dependent macros that get you the current function name: e.g. `__FUNCTION__`. But nothing that will convert a variable into a function name.

Comment: DataGuard should take also string representing function, and then MACRO might be used at call site to void to repeat function twice.

Comment: @MartinYork: `__FUNCTION__` would "give" `DataGuard<T,D>::DataGuard` not function from the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it from the inside the function.

You can do externally:

```
DATAGUARD( MyObject ) guard( data, MyObjectGet, ptr );
```

I would change this:

```
#define  DG(data, func, ptr)     data, func, ptr, #func

// usage is now:
DATAGUARD( MyObject )  guard(DG(guard, data, MyObjectGet, ptr));
```

You will notice that we pass the function pointer and the name of the function pointer as a quoted string as the last parameter. You can use this string as part of your error message.